# '$' of object [object Window] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, actinic

Just discovered an issue with the sorting plugin used on our cart, was working fine yesterday, and no changes have been made to it. The site is located [here](http://www.firesidexpressions.com). 
I realize there is a mess of javascript and jquery in the HEAD, and I am sure that is not helping matters. The error I'm getting is **Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function**. Is there possibly a jQuery conflict going on here?

Comment: Well, in Chrome, my Debug window says there is a 404 trying to load script `http://www.firesidexpressions.com/NaN`. That'd be a place to start.

Comment: You have something like this in the page <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="NaN">

Comment: Also jQuery is loaded fine in my FF and I was able to access $ also. Try clearing the browser cache and check again. Maybe some cached files are corrupt. Also you are loading jQuery two times from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js and http://www.firesidexpressions.com/acatalog/jquery-1.3.2.min.js

Comment: Was able to fix the NaN error, but that still hasn't resolved the original issue. I did remove the duplicate calls to including jQuery as well. In addition, the code is already using noConflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kiranvj vcsjones both had the right idea about what to tackle first. We have one of those badges on there that was trying to append a string when it was expected a number, hence the Nan error. Fixed that, but still getting the error. I haven't uploaded my changes as this site takes a while, but I did fix the NaN eror, but still have the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

Rap any Javascript code in a closure,

```
(function($){
    // code goes here
})(jQuery);
```

This will then prevent any problems with jQuery and the use of the $ as what your doing is creating a function that takes in the $ as a name, this then forces every thing inside closure  will use the function local copy of $

Comment: That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the jquery variable with the noConflict method.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var J=$.noConflict();
 J(".class").hide(); //use J instead of $ now
</script>
```

That way you KNOW it's not a jquery conflict with the $ character

Comment: We were already using noConflict, sadly enough. I inherited this code, and man is it ugly.

Answer (score 0):

another contributing factor to your issue is your loading both jquery and jqueryui twice.

Comment: Removed the duplicate entries, still have original issue.